# How to optimize this eloquent query? (check that a date range is not already taken)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Here is my Eloquent query, which allows to check if a date is already occupied or not, according to a "started_at" and an "ends_at".

```php
$bookings = Booking::where(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
            $q->orWhere('started_at', '>=', $start)
                ->where('started_at', '<=', $end)
                ->where('status', '!==', Booking::STATUS_CANCELED);
            })
            ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
                $q->where('ends_at', '>=', $start)
                    ->where('ends_at', '<=', $end)
                    ->where('status', '!==', Booking::STATUS_CANCELED);
            })
            ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
                $q->where('started_at', '<', $start)
                    ->where('ends_at', '>', $end)
                    ->where('status', '!==', Booking::STATUS_CANCELED);
            })->get();
```

The query works, but I think it's a bit long, it can probably be shortened.

Especially for the where that checks that the status is not "cancelled".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

your query could look like that :

```
       $bookings = Booking::where('status', '!==', Booking::STATUS_CANCELED)
        ->where(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
            $q->where('started_at', '<=', $end)
                ->orWhere('started_at', '>=', $start);
        })
        ->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
            $q->where('ends_at', '>=', $start)
                ->where('ends_at', '<=', $end);
        })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start, $end) {
            $q->where('started_at', '<', $start)
                ->where('ends_at', '>', $end);
        })->get();
```

Comment: I've already tested it and it doesn't work like that

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this out, but something like this should work:

```php
$bookings = Booking::where('status', '!=', Booking::STATUS_CANCELED)
    ->where(function ($query) use ($start, $end) {
        $query->whereBetween('started_at', [$start, $end])
            ->orWhereBetween('ends_at', [$start, $end])
            ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($start, $end) {
                $query->where('started_at', '<', $start)
                    ->where('ends_at', '>', $end);
            });
    });
```